# The constructor TextView() is undefined

Tags: java, android, textview

I made a method to create textviews with certain CSS styles, but I placed the code in a class and it suddenly stopped working. I firstly had "this" since it was in the main class, but now it's in a subclass and "this" doesn't work there, so I removed it and now I get a different error which I have no idea on how to fix.

```
public class textviewscreate {

public void textviewToevoegen(RelativeLayout relativeLayout) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams;       
    String[] naam = {"Bouw onderdeel", "Kapconstructie","Kapconstructieve bevesiging","Doorbuiging","Vochtinwerking","Dakconstructie","Constructieve bevesiging","Doorbuiging","Vochtinwerking","Waterkerende lagen","Waterdichtheid (folie)laag","Lekwaterafvoerend vermogen","Detaillering aan dakvoet","Thermischeisolatie","Bevestiging","Aansluitdetails","Isolerend vermogen","Dakpannen en vorsten","Conditie dakpannen en vorsten","Breukschade","Vorstschade","Afschilfering","Aangroei algen en mos"};
    TextView[] textView = new TextView[22];
     //1st TextView
    textView[0] = new TextView();   //This gives an error, first was new TextView(this);

    relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    textView[0].setId(1); // changed id from 0 to 1
    textView[0].setText(naam[0].toUpperCase());
    relativeLayout.addView(textView[0], relativeLayoutParams);
    relativeLayoutParams.setMargins(24, 39, 0, 0);
    // All othet Textviews
    for (int i = 1; i < textView.length; i++) { 
        relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);      
        relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                    textView[i-1].getId());
            relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,
                textView[i-1].getId()); // added top alignment rule

         textView[i] = new TextView(); //Also an error firstly new TextView(this);
            textView[i].setText(naam[i]);
            textView[i].setId(i+1);
            relativeLayout.addView(textView[i], relativeLayoutParams);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `TextView` using `context`, which can be passed in the constructor or method of a non activity class. Like:

`public void textviewToevoegen(RelativeLayout relativeLayout)` becomes:

```
public void textviewToevoegen(RelativeLayout relativeLayout, Context context)
```

And the same is passed to the

```
textView[i] = new TextView();
```

which uses the context, becomes

```
textView[i] = new TextView(context);
```

When you use `textviewToevoegen` and pass the `relativeLayout` from your activity, pass `this` or that `activity`'s `context`.

Refer: [public constructors of the TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#TextView(android.content.Context))

Comment: to the one who voted down..would be good to comment why the down vote

Answer (score 2):

There is no empty constructor for TextView. Since you are not in a sublcass of activity or fragment you should provide, at least, the context  as parameter for the method:

```
public void textviewToevoegen(Context context, RelativeLayout relativeLayout) {
    textView[0] = new TextView(context);
```

or in your case, if the RelativeLayout is a valid object you can use getContext

```
public void textviewToevoegen(RelativeLayout relativeLayout) {
    textView[0] = new TextView(relativeLayout.getContext());
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

When you provide your custom view class then you have to given some overloaded constructor which behave your custom view as android built-in view like (TextView,Button etc.).

```
public class textviewscreate {

    private Context context;

    public textviewscreate(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    public textviewscreate(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    public textviewscreate(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void textviewToevoegen(Context context,RelativeLayout relativeLayout) {
        this.context = context;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams;
        String[] naam = {"Bouw onderdeel", "Kapconstructie","Kapconstructieve bevesiging","Doorbuiging","Vochtinwerking","Dakconstructie","Constructieve bevesiging","Doorbuiging","Vochtinwerking","Waterkerende lagen","Waterdichtheid (folie)laag","Lekwaterafvoerend vermogen","Detaillering aan dakvoet","Thermischeisolatie","Bevestiging","Aansluitdetails","Isolerend vermogen","Dakpannen en vorsten","Conditie dakpannen en vorsten","Breukschade","Vorstschade","Afschilfering","Aangroei algen en mos"};
        TextView[] textView = new TextView[22];
        //1st TextView
        textView[0] = new TextView();   //This gives an error, first was new TextView(this);

        relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        textView[0].setId(1); // changed id from 0 to 1
        textView[0].setText(naam[0].toUpperCase());
        relativeLayout.addView(textView[0], relativeLayoutParams);Ij
        relativeLayoutParams.setMargins(24, 39, 0, 0);
        // All othet Textviews
        for (int i = 1; i < textView.length; i++) {
            relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
                    textView[i-1].getId());
            relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,
                    textView[i-1].getId()); // added top alignment rule

            textView[i] = new TextView(); //Also an error firstly new TextView(this);
            textView[i].setText(naam[i]);
            textView[i].setId(i+1);
            relativeLayout.addView(textView[i], relativeLayoutParams);
        }
    }
}
```